# Why can't I find any wither skeletons?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I recently found a nether fortress that happens to cross into a warped forest (I don’t know if that is important, I thought it might be useful to know) and I can’t find any either skeletons spawning anywhere. Everything else that spawns naturally in a nether fortress is there, but I can’t seem to find wither skeletons, which are the one reason I even went there. Do you know why they aren’t there?

Comment: Please don't answer in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Wither skeletons always spawn in Nether Fortresses, but there are a few possibilities on why you aren't finding them.

1. **The light level is too high.** Wither skeletons can only spawn in light levels of 7 or less. The light level may be higher from the shroomlights in the warped tress.
2. **They may be spawning in places you can't see.** Sometimes, wither skeletons can spawn in closed of areas of the fortress, or rooms that you can't see.
3. **They are just wandering off.** If the fortress is on the same level as the ground, they could just be wandering away from the fortress.

I would try exploring the fortress and removing light sources nearby, and see if that helps.